# Rewrite Rule return 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, raspberry-pi

I just setup Apache on my Raspberry Pi. I've enabled the Rewrite Mode for shunk all the API request on the `index.php`. In my project root (of my rest API) I've configured the `.htaccess` as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /api/v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now my project is located inside the /API/v1 folder, the `.htaccess` working for all webserver where I upload the project so now I don't understand why I get this error:

> The requested URL /api/v1/index.php was not found on this server..
>   But I don't understood why this working on my other hosting and not on my raspberry.

Comment: You are developing an API on your own...better check the Slim Framework...Silex is a good alternative too...

Comment: my api working on other hosting.. I think is an api problem

Comment: But it works on your local dev environment right?

Comment: My api working on localhost (Bitnami) and also on my xlogic hosting payment and other hosting... I setup an apache webserver on my raspberry pi but I get this error. I don't know, but seems that there is a problem with the Rewrite mod, I also have it enabled...

Comment: it may be as simple as `RewriteBase /API/v1/` - uppercase in the path makes a difference on some systems

Comment: uhm my folder are in lowercase.. If I put in the url http://myraspip/projects/api/v1/index.php?uri=transaction all working good.. Seems that the Rewrite cannot find the index.php file in the base path :\

Comment: you did write it in uppercase in the question ;). hmm, if myraspip/projects/api... is the full and working url, than the raspi-apache is using the folder over projects/ as documentRoot....I think you either need to configure the apache so that projects/ is the documentRoot or use /projects/api/v1/ as RewriteBase